# Changes to android widget not loading

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, widget

I am developing an app that contains a simple widget to display some information. Using eclipse with the andriod plugin, I have made a number of changes to the widget.xml config file, and also the widget_layout.xml files. When I load the project either onto the emulator or a device, the changes are not reflected in the widget.

I've tried:
+ rebuilding the project;
+ closing ecliplse, phone, emulator and retrying;
+ removing the app from the phone and emulator through settings before loading back in eclipse;

It seems as though the widget files have been cached somewhere and resaving them seems to make no difference to the package that's sent to the phone. Is there a setting in eclipse that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Appears that the problem was the manifest file having the widget.xml referenced twice. For some reason it worked the first time and then refused to accept changed widget files (perhaps the error was hidden).

If you get this problem make sure you've only got one intent receiver for the APPWIDGET_UPDATE action and debug from there.